# Lightning - Cases: Activity History Missing 'Log a call' and 'Email' buttons

Tags: activityhistory, log-a-call

1)On the Cases object page layout, I've added the related list Activity History.

2)In the page layout, I've opened the wrench on the related list and made sure the buttons for 'Log a Call' and 'Email' are checked.

3)In the page layout, I've added the buttons to the page layout for lightning.
[image]

4)'Log a call' and 'Email' are configured in Global Settings and these buttons appear on other object's related lists.

5)While editing the Cases page, I'm using Related List-Single in Tabs and the buttons 'Log a Call' and 'Email' are missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cases by default have a feed-based style layout which essentially means the actions will show up in chatter, not in the top right corner as you might expect with other layouts.

It's a bit of a holdover from classic but here is more info on the feed-based layouts: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.feed_based_layouts_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you @Rostro! I researched all prior answers to similar questions and nothing made sense. I just added the Chatter element on the Cases page which allows me to be able to Log a Call, Send an Email and Add a Task and records all activity under one tab. Not perfect, but it works.